# Jquery .ajax() function not returning values from codeigniter controller

Tags: codeigniter, jquery, codeigniter-2

I have a site i'm working on and i'm trying to make an ajax request to a controller (codeigniter framework). I see in firebug that my controller is receiving my post value just fine but for some reason it is not sending back a response. I've set it up to be VERY simple without a database call at this point just for testing and its still not working. Any ideas?

Here is my form in my view:

```
<div class="purchaseState">
     <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="grayGrad"/>
</div>      
<div>
     <ul id="cityResults">
          <!-- AJAX results here -->
     </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my controller returning the value:

```
function citySearch() { 
     echo '<li>test</li>';
}
```

Here is my Jquery ajax

```
//New City Search
$('#city').keyup( function() {

     var city = $('#city').val();

    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "page/citySearch",
         data: { city: city },
         }).done(function( data ) {
         $('ul#cityResults').append(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Just give a try. Remove the data property from ajax and try this. Also in your browser, hit the url directly and check the response. Let' see what is happening!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use ajax `success` callback:

```
$('#city').keyup(function() {

 var city = $('#city').val();

    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "page/citySearch",
         data: { city: city },
         success: function(data) {
            $('ul#cityResults').append(data);
         } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried that earlier, just tried it again, didn't work. This is weird.

Comment: @DanielWhite you should use success callback, `done()` is not useful here, have you tried echoing something outside of the function?

Comment: I've changed my JS to the above (instead of the done() function) and I tried accessing the "page/citySearch" in another window and I can see the test list element fine.

Comment: I figured it out. My url was not resolving correctly.

I had to change my url from:

url: 'page/citySearch';

to:

url: '<?php site_url('page/citySearch'); ?>';

Answer (score 0):

Please change the url in the AJAX function in the following way.

```
$('#city').keyup(function() {
var city = $('#city').val();
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "<?php echo base_url; ?>page/citySearch",
     data: { city: city },
     success: function(data) {
        $('ul#cityResults').append(data);
     } 
});
});
```